Shell Bash Comparing expr result of IF
I am learning shell bash now, and tried to figure it out how to compare expr result on IF condition.
Basically want to return only odd natural numbers
The code
a=1

while [ $a -lt 10 ]
do
    echo "test " $a % 2 " = " `expr $a % 2`
    if [`expr $a % 2`] 
    then
        echo $a
    fi
   
    a=`expr $a + 1`
done


The result
test  1 % 2  =  1
main.ksh[8]: [1]: not found
test  2 % 2  =  0
main.ksh[8]: [0]: not found
test  3 % 2  =  1
main.ksh[8]: [1]: not found
test  4 % 2  =  0
main.ksh[8]: [0]: not found
test  5 % 2  =  1
main.ksh[8]: [1]: not found
test  6 % 2  =  0
main.ksh[8]: [0]: not found
test  7 % 2  =  1
main.ksh[8]: [1]: not found
test  8 % 2  =  0
main.ksh[8]: [0]: not found
test  9 % 2  =  1
main.ksh[8]: [1]: not found

I wish the result should be
1
3
5
7
9

Check your script with shellcheck.

Please read the info on whatever tags you use in questions, e.g. the [tag:bash] tag says "IMPORTANT NOTE: Do not ask a bash question until after you have copy/pasted your script into http://shellcheck.net and fixed all of the issues it tells you about." - doing that would have solved your problem for you.

Don't use expr in the first place. It's an artifact of the 1970s and has no place in modern scripts -- current shells have math syntax built in and don't need the inefficiency of starting a separate executable for arithmetic.

Here's how to do what you're trying to do using bash builtins:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for (( a=1; a < 10; a++ )); do
    printf 'test %s %% 2 = %s\n' "$a" "$(( a % 2 ))"
    if (( a % 2 )); then
        printf '%s\n' "$a"
    fi
done

It's not the end of the world if you do the above since it's just using builtins and so won't be too slow but a shell (e.g. bash) is a tool designed to manipulate (create/destroy) files and processes and sequence calls to other tools, it's not a tool designed to manipulate text, so if you were really going to write a shell script to do this using mandatory POSIX tools then the only bash part would be the call to awk (the POSIX-standard tool for general purpose text manipulation, which includes doing math):
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN {
        for ( a=1; a < 10; a++ ) {
            printf "test %s %% 2 = %s\n", a, (a % 2)
            if ( a % 2 ) {
                print a
            }
        }
    }
'

Since you're just learning - see why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for info on other issues around using shell to manipulate text.

It's look like the only thing missing is some space, lol.
#!/bin/sh

a=1

while [ $a -lt 10 ]
do
    echo "test " $a % 2 " = " `expr $a % 2`
    if [ `expr $a % 2` == 1 ]
    then
        echo $a
    fi
   
    a=`expr $a + 1`
done

Result
test  1 % 2  =  1
1
test  2 % 2  =  0
test  3 % 2  =  1
3
test  4 % 2  =  0
test  5 % 2  =  1
5
test  6 % 2  =  0
test  7 % 2  =  1
7
test  8 % 2  =  0
test  9 % 2  =  1
9


You tagged your question with bash but then your shebang in this answer is using sh. Which of those 2 different shells are you actually trying to use in your script? This answer contains multiple other problems, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78646725/shell-bash-comparing-expr-result-of-if#comment138659483_78646725 for how to identify and fix them.

There are more bugs here. For example, == isn't guaranteed to be supported by POSIX-standard [ (and when you use sh instead of bash or ksh you're asking only for a guarantee of POSIX-baseline functionality) -- the standard comparison operator is just =. And using expr in the first place is completely unnecessary -- any sh compliant with the POSIX.2 standard published in the early 90s supports $((a % 2)) to do arithmetic built into the shell itself, no /usr/bin/expr needed.

(There's a major performance difference between built-in shell math and spawning an external subprocess -- try running your loop for a much larger number of iterations and timing it, one version doing things the expr way and the other built-in; you might also want to direct output to /dev/null so the time needed for output to be written doesn't throw off the benchmark)

Wow, thank you guys. That's tons of useful answer. I was suffered for few weeks getting to understand this language. literally, maybe I am not putting the correct question on google to get the correct answer.
